# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when populating RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting an error every so often when I try to populate my RecyclerView but the error seems to happening internally in the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

I populate the RecyclerView from my database then add the images to my adapter using this

```
List<WImage> images;

public void addImages(LinkedHashMap<Integer,WImage> newImages){
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,WImage> entry : newImages.entrySet()){
        addImage(entry.getValue(),entry.getKey());
    }
}

public void addImage(WImage image, int position){
    images.add(position,image);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(position, 1);

}
```

What is weird is when the app first loads it is fine and displays everything correctly but if I replace what was currently in the RecyclerView with a different set of images based on a database query then come back with the initial images again I get this error.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=16 srcPos=0 dst.length=0 dstPos=0 length=16
            at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
            at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$LazySpanLookup.ensureSize(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2277)
            at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$LazySpanLookup.offsetForAddition(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2323)
            at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.handleUpdate(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1280)
            at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onItemsAdded(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1253)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.dispatchUpdate(RecyclerView.java:406)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.onDispatchSecondPass(RecyclerView.java:422)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.consumePostponedUpdates(AdapterHelper.java:119)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1896)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.resumeRequestLayout(RecyclerView.java:1101)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:155)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it goes through all the images just fine but when its ready to call `onBindViewHolder` again it crashes.

When I change the data in the RecyclerView I remove everything first with this before populating with the new data from the query

```
public void removeAll(){
    images.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I also tried inserting them all at once and then calling `notifyItemRangeInserted` with the start position and the total number of images but it still crashsed with the same error.

**EDIT**

it seems to happen when I hit about 20 or so items that I need to put into the Grid. If I just use `notifyDatasetChanged` it seems to work fine but I want to use `notifyItemRangeInserted` so I get the nice insert animation

Has anyone else seen this problem?

**EDIT2**

here is my `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_normal_grid_cell, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

and my `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    final WImage image = images.get(i);
    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v,i,image);
        }
    });

    holder.heart.setActivated(image.getLikeDislike());

    holder.heart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri.Builder ub = SyncProvider.CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE.buildUpon();
            ub.appendPath(String.valueOf(image.getId()));
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            if(image.getLikeDislike()){
                values.put(SyncProvider.LIKE,0);
                holder.heart.setActivated(false);
                image.setLikeDislike(false);
            }else{
                values.put(SyncProvider.LIKE,1);
                holder.heart.setActivated(true);
                image.setLikeDislike(true);
            }
            values.put(SyncProvider.IMAGE_CHANGED,1);
            context.getContentResolver().update(ub.build(),values,null,null);
        }
    });
    if(cancelPotentialDownload(image.getUri(),holder.imageview)){
        LoadImageTask task = new LoadImageTask(holder.imageview,image.getThumbUri());
        holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(new AsyncBitmap(task));
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

here is what I do when I replace the adapter

on selected index change of my nav drawer I init my loader to make a query

```
public void initLoader(int page){
    if(currentPage != page && mAdapter != null){
        mAdapter.removeAll();
        hashImages.clear();
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(currentPage);
    }
    currentPage = page;
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(page,null,this);
}
```

then in my onLoadFinished of my loader I add the objects to the adapter

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                WImage image = new WImage(cursor);
                if(!hashImages.containsKey(image.getId())){
                    newImages.put(tempHash.size(),image);
                }else if(image.getImageChanged()){
                    update = true;
                }
                int pos = tempHash.size();
                tempHash.put(image.getId(),pos);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    if(newImages.size() > 0){
            mAdapter.addImages(newImages);
        }
```

Comment: @pskink what part? the code I posted is in my adapter

Comment: unfortunately, this might be a bug in the grid layout manager :(. Can you post a bug report to b.android.com w/ a sample app that reproduces the crash?

Comment: btw, can you also post the code that replaces the adapter? Something might be wrong there. (e.g. missing some events)

Comment: @yigit see edit 3 for that code

Comment: i'm sorry to inform you that this looks like a bug in StaggeredGrid. It fails to grow its internal bookkeeping array during a predictive animation. I'll create an internal ticket for this but feel free to create a bug report on b.android.com to be notified when issue is fixed.

Comment: @yigit I have been trying to recreate the problem in a sample application but I have been unable to do so successfully. I will post a bug report if I can reproduce the issue or even just link to this question directly i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64039/discussion-between-yigit-and-tyczj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is triggered by https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77846. 
Can you replace `notifyDataSetChanged` calls with specific notify events (`notifyItemRemoved/Added`) and see if you can reproduce it?

Comment: yes this error still occurs when removing one at a time

Comment: Hmm interesting, my test case passes if I call

    `mAdapter.mItems.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    /* load data*/
    mAdapter.mItems.addAll(0, newSize);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newSize);`

and crashes if I do:
  
    `mAdapter.mItems.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    /* load data*/
    mAdapter.mItems.addAll(0, newSize);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newSize);`

Comment: If you want I can upload my project to github later to see if it may help you out (or me)

Comment: yea it would help. The bug is trivial to fix but I want to understand what is going on here because fixing this may just unlock another bug. A sample project would be very helpful. if you need to add it as a private repo, my github name is the same w/ my SO name. Thanks.

Comment: here is the repo. https://github.com/tyczj/CrashExample I took out all the unnecessary parts needed to register the app so it should load right but but if it does not let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot. I verified the fix works for your app as well. It will be released in the next update.

Comment: was it anything I did or how I had something set up?

Comment: no, this is a bug about SGLM. The method in question has a bug (where it may return size less than the asked position). Also, the assumption there (limiting lookup table size w/ adapter size) is wrong because adapter size is updated lazily. Btw, lookup table is where it keeps the span information for views. (e.g. which column the view belongs)

Answer (score 7):

This bug has been solved by google in version **21.0.2**:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This crash happen when you try to `notifyDataSetChanged/notifyItemRemoved/Added/change` while `RecyclerView  isComputingLayout`

> This case may happen if you have some custom logic to change adapter
>   contents in response to a View callback
>
> In these cases, you should just postpone the change using a Handler

**DON'T notify change** until `RecyclerView.isComputingLayout()` return false.

```
 /**
     * Returns whether RecyclerView is currently computing a layout.
     * <p>
     * If this method returns true, it means that RecyclerView is in a lockdown state and any
     * attempt to update adapter contents will result in an exception because adapter contents
     * cannot be changed while RecyclerView is trying to compute the layout.
     * <p>
     * It is very unlikely that your code will be running during this state as it is
     * called by the framework when a layout traversal happens or RecyclerView starts to scroll
     * in response to system events (touch, accessibility etc).
     * <p>
     * This case may happen if you have some custom logic to change adapter contents in
     * response to a View callback (e.g. focus change callback) which might be triggered during a
     * layout calculation. In these cases, you should just postpone the change using a Handler or a
     * similar mechanism.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if RecyclerView is currently computing a layout, <code>false</code>
     *         otherwise
     */
    public boolean isComputingLayout() {
        return mLayoutOrScrollCounter > 0;
    }
```